# Problems getting Falcon to run on Mac

Tags: python, macos, six, falcon, falconframework

I'm having a challenge running Falcon on my Mac.  I'm using python 2.7 along with pycharm for some time with no issues.

There seems to be several related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643052/importerror-no-module-named-http-cookies-error-when-installing-cherrypy-3-2) , [here](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/81), and [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/CherryPy-3-2-2-No-module-named-Cookie-td4335625.html), but still seem to have the same problem.

I've spent many hours trying to get this to work and everything appears to point to the six package and SSL.

Following are my efforts so far.  Any help greatly appreciated

```
MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.10.2

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ pip install six --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ sudo pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient
Password:
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyopenssl in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ndg-httpsclient in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ sudo pip install six --upgrade
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ sudo pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyopenssl in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ndg-httpsclient in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ sudo pip install gunicorn --upgrade
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/my.user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: gunicorn in /Library/Python/2.7/site-package

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ cat things.py
# things.py

# Let's get this party started
import falcon


# Falcon follows the REST architectural style, meaning (among
# other things) that you think in terms of resources and state
# transitions, which map to HTTP verbs.
class ThingsResource:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        """Handles GET requests"""
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200  # This is the default status
        resp.body = ('\nTwo things awe me most, the starry sky '
                     'above me and the moral law within me.\n'
                     '\n'
                     '    ~ Immanuel Kant\n\n')

# falcon.API instances are callable WSGI apps
app = falcon.API()

# Resources are represented by long-lived class instances
things = ThingsResource()

# things will handle all requests to the '/things' URL path
app.add_route('/things', things)

MYMACBOOKPRO:falcon my.user$ gunicorn things:app
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66479] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66479] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (66479)
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66479] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66482] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 66482
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66482] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/my.user/falcon/things.py", line 4, in <module>
    import falcon
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from falcon.api import API, DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 22, in <module>
    from falcon.request import Request, RequestOptions
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/request.py", line 35, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_cookies import SimpleCookie
ImportError: No module named http_cookies
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/my.user/falcon/things.py", line 4, in <module>
    import falcon
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from falcon.api import API, DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/api.py", line 22, in <module>
    from falcon.request import Request, RequestOptions
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/falcon/request.py", line 35, in <module>
    from six.moves.http_cookies import SimpleCookie
ImportError: No module named http_cookies
[2015-11-20 08:38:42 -0500] [66482] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 66482)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 189, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 174, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 541, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 214, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with your environment. I use Mac and I never had a problem. To make sure, try to use virtualenv.

```bash
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv test
source ./test/bin/activate
pip install falcon
pip install gunicorn
cd go/to/your/falcon/app/path
gunicorn things:app
```

If it's doesnt work, try reinstalling pip. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command:

`$ pip install falcon`

will install falcon version `0.3.0` which gives error: `ImportError: No module named http_cookies`

Install falcon using package from [python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/falcon)

Then install package like so:

`$ pip install falcon-1.0.0rc1.tar.gz`